# How to return Unauthorized in an Asp.Net Core Custom Authorization Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a custom authorization filter for my API which checks against a token that is saved in the database.

So like this

```
override public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("X-CustomToken"))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
            return;
        }

        var headerToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers
                         .Where(a => a.Key.ToLower() == "x-customtoken").FirstOrDefault();
        var company= _repository.GetCompanyByToken(headerToken.Value);
        if (company == null)
        {
            context.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
            return;
        }

        _myFactory.SetCurrentCompany(company);            
    }
```

the problem is that as I've read in other questions asked here, it is redirected to the login page like it does for front-end controllers. The solution I usually read is to override this behaviour entirely. However my project has a front-end and an API in the same solution so I only need to override this when my custom attribute is used.

thanks